# Set default options for all multiselect instances using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i'm using this plugin / widget to style select menus http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

I have multiple select menus on one page and would like all of them to have the same options. You can see my current setup here **http://jsfiddle.net/peter/htb48/4/**

The problem is that with this method each select has to have a unique ID which it shouldn't. These select menus are in a dynamic table and i need each select menu to be id="one-group"

On the widget site it says to use

```
$.ech.multiselect.prototype.options.selectedText = "# of # selected";
```

I'm not sure how to use this with my code to give all the select menus my current set of options. Any help is appreciated

Comment: not sure what you are asking. they are currently styled the same...you definitely don't want to have two elements with the same ID...

Comment: Instead of using my function I need one that uses the $.ech. function so I can give all the select menus the same options and let them have the same ID. I'm not trying to restyle them, I need to let users select different options from each select menu, and not have unique IDs

Comment: Right now if they have the same ID one select group changes the others select option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my best guess for what you are trying to ask here is that you want to be able to set options for multiselects differently on your page.

just select the id instead of going to $("select") go to $("#one-groups") etc.

see http://jsfiddle.net/LPS3w/

Comment: The problem is with say 2 or more forms with id="one-groups" it'll only initialize the first select menu found on the page with that ID and the other doesn't appear at all. I'll have these select menus in a table one on each row of a table. One column will have say "one-groups" the next column will have "two-groups" etc

Comment: you CAN'T have multiple elements with the same ID. the whole point of ID is to have a unique element. why do you need to have elements with the same ID?

Comment: if you want to have multiple of the same add a class. so add class="multipleEdit" to each of your select menus and you can select it like $("select.multipleEdit").multiselect({...etc

Comment: Just tried without any ID's after looking at some of their demo's and see I don't need it at all.

Comment: you do if you ever want to add different options to a different type of select